# How can I log progress of multiple sql queries in a single JdbcTemplate execute() and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, logging, jdbctemplate

I have a SQL script with many statements which I execute using JdbcTemplate.execute(). Some queries are slow and I'd like to write progress of the whole script to the logs.

As it stands, I only get logs written once all the statements have completed.

Comment: The DB is Postgres, I've updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: I don't understand whether you are calling `execute` only once with one huge sting containing all statements or are you calling `execute` several times.

Comment: The execute is called only once with all statements. This is the problem. If I called each separately I could see the progress of the statements as they were logged.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to get what you want. Use the **PostgreSQL server log**. Set the options in the config file `postgresql.conf` and reload, or set parameters per session like this:

Log every single SQL statement:

```
set log_statement = 'all';
```

Or hunt for slow queries in particular, for example: everything that takes longer than 1000 ms:

```
set log_min_duration_statement = 1000;
```

The manual about [logging-parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html):

> log_statement (enum)
>
> Controls which SQL statements are logged. Valid values are none (off), ddl, mod, and all (all statements).

If you log everything remember to turn it off afterwards or the log files may grow huge.

> log_min_duration_statement (integer)
>
> Causes the duration of each completed statement to be logged if the statement ran for at least the specified number of milliseconds. Setting this to zero prints all statement durations. (...)

The manual on [how to set parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/config-setting.html).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I don't have access to the server side logs. I need a client side solution if possible.